# Avro serialization

Tags: java, avro

When I try to send a message to Kafka topic I am getting the following error

```
! org.apache.avro.UnresolvedUnionException: Not in union ["null",{"type":"long","logicalType":"timestamp-millis"}]: 2020-03-06T04:41:43.839Z
```

Here is my part of schema:

```
record BookingRequestFailedRecord {

     FailureCategoryType failureCategoryType;
     union {PaymentErrorRecord, null} paymentError = null;
     union {null, string} errorCode = null;
     union {null, string} errorDescription = null;
     union {null, timestamp_ms} createDate = null;
     union {null, timestamp_ms} publishedDate = null;
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this error?

Comment: It's a known issue, see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-1891

Comment: `2020-03-06T04:41:43.839Z` is not a long